# not able to retrieve jwt property on fastify instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, backend, fastify

i'm here because i'm starting to get frustrated about fastify jwt implementation with typescript.

This is my index.ts:

```
import Fastify, { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify'
import { config as dotenvConfig } from 'dotenv';
import { TypeBoxTypeProvider } from '@fastify/type-provider-typebox'
import fastifyPlugin from 'fastify-plugin'
import { 
  IQuerystring,
  IHeaders,
  IReply
} from './shared/interfaces';
import DBConnector from './plugins/database';
import register from './routes/register';
import login from './routes/login';
import jwt from './plugins/jwt';

dotenvConfig();

const server: FastifyInstance = Fastify().withTypeProvider<TypeBoxTypeProvider>()

const APP_PORT = parseInt(process.env.APP_PORT || '8080', 10)

server.register(fastifyPlugin(DBConnector))
server.register(register)
server.register(fastifyPlugin(jwt))
server.register(login)

server.listen({port: APP_PORT}, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
  console.log(` Server running at ${address} and listening on port: ${APP_PORT} `)
})
```

This is my plugin  where i define the jwt logic:

```
import { FastifyInstance, FastifyError } from "fastify";
import fastifyPlugin from "fastify-plugin";

/**
 * @param { FastifyInstance } server
 */

async function jwt(server: FastifyInstance){
  const { SECRET } = process.env
  server.register(require('@fastify/jwt'), {
    secret: SECRET
  })
}

export default fastifyPlugin(jwt)
```

and this is the login logic where i want to release the token on user login:

```
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify'
import fastifyPlugin from 'fastify-plugin'
import { UserLogin, UserLoginType } from '../../shared/schemas/user'
import { IUserLoginReply } from '../../shared/interfaces'
import { comparePassword } from '../../plugins/hashPassword'

/**
 *@param {FastifyInstance} server
*/

async function Login(server: FastifyInstance){

  server.post<{ Body: UserLoginType, Reply: IUserLoginReply }>(
    '/signin', 
    { 
      schema: {
        body: UserLogin
      },
    },
    async (request, reply) => {
      try{
        const { email, password } = request.body

        //check if user exists
        const users = server.mongo.db?.collection('users')

        const user = await users?.findOne({ email: email })

        //if no block the execution by sending an error to the client
        if(!user){
          console.log('User non presente nel db')
          const userErrorResponse: IUserLoginReply = { 400: { error: 'l\'utente non esiste nel db' } };
          return reply.status(500).send(userErrorResponse);
        }

        //check password
        const isPasswordMatching = await comparePassword(password.trim(), user.password);
        
        if(!isPasswordMatching){
          console.log('Password nel login errata')
          const pwdErrorResponse: IUserLoginReply = { 400: { error: 'Password d\'accesso errata' } };
          return reply.status(500).send(pwdErrorResponse);
        }

        //if yes release the token
        const token = server.jwt.sign({ email: user.email }, { expiresIn: '4h' })
        const successResponse: IUserLoginReply = { 200: { success: true }}
        return reply.status(200).send(successResponse)

      }catch (error) {
        console.log('Errore del server');
        const err: IUserLoginReply = { 500: { error: 'Errore del server' } };
        reply.status(500).send(err);
      }
    })
    
}

export default Login
```

The problem is when i declare the const token, looks like i'm not able to retrieve the jwt property on FastifyInstance. Could someone explain me please? Thanks in advance